# How do I use Set- commands with AzureRM and Application Gateway?

Tags: azure, powershell

I am trying to run the following commands to **change** the settings on an **existing** Rule in my Azure Application Gateway:

```
    $updatedAppGW = Set-AzureRmApplicationGatewayRequestRoutingRule -ApplicationGateway $AppGW `
        -Name $ChosenSubscription.httpsRule `
        -RuleType Basic `
        -BackendAddressPool $backendPool `
        -BackendHttpSettings $httpSettings

    # Save Gateway configuration
    Write-Host "[$(__LINE__)]  Attempting to save changes to the Application Gateway..." -ForegroundColor Cyan
    Set-AzureRmApplicationGateway -ApplicationGateway $updatedAppGW | Out-Null
```

The `Set-AzureRmApplicationGatewayRequestRoutingRule` command appears to run correctly (silently, at least).

However, when I then try to "save" the Application Gateway configuration with the command `Set-AzureRmApplicationGateway` I receive the error `Set-AzureRmApplicationGateway : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`

[image: Console output]

I think this is because I'm not using these "Set" commands correctly.

I read online that when I run `Set-AzureRmApplicationGatewayRequestRoutingRule`, I'm only actually making changes to the Rule in local memory. I then have to save the changes of the Application Gateway.

Is this true? If so... how do I actually save the Application Gateway configuration in this context? Earlier in my script, when using `Add-AzureRm` commands (such as `Add-AzureRmApplicationGatewayBackendAddressPool`), I've immediately (following line) run `Set-AzureRmApplicationGateway` and it has worked as intended.

I have also tried altering the `Set-AzureRmApplicationGateway` command in the code block at the top of this post to use my original `$AppGW` variable instead of this `$updatedAppGW` variable which I *think* my `Set-AzureRmApplicationGatewayRequestRoutingRule` command is producing. Neither works - identical error.

### EDIT: Additional diagnosis

Adding the following Write-Host output...

```
    Write-Host "[$(__LINE__)]  Retrieved AG Rule '$($rule.Name)'." -ForegroundColor Magenta
    Write-Host "[$(__LINE__)]  Attempting to change this rule to point at Backend Address Pool '$($backendPool.Name)' and HTTP Settings '$($httpSettings.Name)'..." -ForegroundColor Cyan

    # Re-retrieve the Application Gateway after saving it earlier
    $AppGW = Get-AzureRmApplicationGateway -Name $ChosenSubscription.appGateway -ResourceGroupName $ChosenSubscription.resourceGroup

    # Re-retrieve the Backend Address Pool and HTTP Settings that we've created, for the sake of updating the rule
    $backendPool = Get-AzureRmApplicationGatewayBackendAddressPool -ApplicationGateway $AppGW -Name $MaintenanceToggleBackendPool
    $httpSettings = Get-AzureRmApplicationGatewayBackendHttpSettings -ApplicationGateway $AppGW -Name $MaintenanceToggleHTTPSetting

    Write-Host "[$(__LINE__)]  `$AppGW.Name $($AppGW.Name)" -ForegroundColor Green
    Write-Host "[$(__LINE__)]  `$AppGW.ProvisioningState $($AppGW.ProvisioningState)" -ForegroundColor Green
    Write-Host "[$(__LINE__)]  `$AppGW.OperationalState $($AppGW.OperationalState)" -ForegroundColor Green

    $updatedAppGW = Set-AzureRmApplicationGatewayRequestRoutingRule -ApplicationGateway $AppGW `
        -Name $ChosenSubscription.httpsRule `
        -RuleType Basic `
        -BackendAddressPool $backendPool `
        -BackendHttpSettings $httpSettings

    Write-Host "[$(__LINE__)]  `$updatedAppGW.Name $($updatedAppGW.Name)" -ForegroundColor Green
    Write-Host "[$(__LINE__)]  `$updatedAppGW.ProvisioningState $($updatedAppGW.ProvisioningState)" -ForegroundColor Green
    Write-Host "[$(__LINE__)]  `$updatedAppGW.OperationalState $($updatedAppGW.OperationalState)" -ForegroundColor Green

    # Save Gateway configuration
    Write-Host "[$(__LINE__)]  Attempting to save changes to the Application Gateway..." -ForegroundColor Cyan
    Set-AzureRmApplicationGateway -ApplicationGateway $updatedAppGW | Out-Null
```

... gives the following console output:

[image: Console output for further diagnosis]

Answer (score 1):

OK, managed to fix the problem myself... *sigh*

On the `Set-AzureRmApplicationGatewayRequestRoutingRule` command, you **must** specify the `-HttpListener` parameter, or it will fail silently.

```
    # Re-retrieve the Backend Address Pool and HTTP Settings that we've created, for the sake of updating the rule
    $backendPool = Get-AzureRmApplicationGatewayBackendAddressPool -ApplicationGateway $AppGW -Name $MaintenanceToggleBackendPool
    $httpSettings = Get-AzureRmApplicationGatewayBackendHttpSettings -ApplicationGateway $AppGW -Name $MaintenanceToggleHTTPSetting
    $httpListener = Get-AzureRmApplicationGatewayHttpListener -ApplicationGateway $AppGW -Name "HttpListenerTest"

    $updatedAppGW = Set-AzureRmApplicationGatewayRequestRoutingRule -ApplicationGateway $AppGW `
        -Name $ChosenSubscription.httpsRule `
        -RuleType Basic `
        -BackendAddressPool $backendPool `
        -BackendHttpSettings $httpSettings `
        -HttpListener $httpListener
```

This is why the `Set-AzureRmApplicationGateway` command wasn't working properly - it had a malformed `RequestRoutingRule` in its memory.

Comment: That's frustrating since the help file says -httpListener isn't required.

Comment: Not my first frustration with the AzureRM cmdlets and I'm sure it won't be my last :) Hopefully my answer will save someone else some time in the future.